# Unify outbound request ip from kubernetes cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes

I have a `kubernetes` cluster having 5 nodes, deployed on aws using [kops](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops).

I have a setup a load balancer and `ingress-nginx` controller for reverse proxy.

So, all incoming request come to a *single ip* which is of the load balancer.

I have an service `admin-srv` inside the cluster which forwards request to two `pods`.

The problem is whenever I make request to some domain `example.com` from these pods, the source ip assigned is random and picked from any `node`

So, one time I hit request it is something like `5.1...`, again if hit the ip becomes `5.2....`

*The domain that I am calling `example.com` they need one `ip` that would not change and they will whitelist that.*

***How it can be achieved?***

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the NAT gateway for this scenario.

So using the NAT gateway all the out bound request will be diverted using the one VM and you will get single IP for the out bound traffic also.

You can read more about the **NAT** : https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview

**AWS** : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Scenario2.html

If you are one the GKE you can take a look on this example of terraform : https://registry.terraform.io/modules/GoogleCloudPlatform/nat-gateway/google/latest/examples/gke-nat-gateway

Comment: Why I can still make outbound request from inside the cluster? Shouldn't be it blocked? It attaches  node's ip on each request.

Comment: yes ideally pod will be using the node when you will be sending the request outside.

Comment: node ip will be the same on which pod is assigned.

Comment: your nodes must in public network or subnet with the external IP so when you request outside it will take the IP of node and send request

Comment: Does it happen because of internet gateway? It is attached by default. After configuring NAT can I remove internet gateway?

Comment: regarding that even i might have to check, but adding the NAT will solve your issue of single engress IP

Comment: Can I attach elastic ip to internet gateway? As internet gateway allowing instances to access to the internet using their public ips. But incoming request on each node's public ip is bocked.

Comment: I have attached NAT and provisioned a elastic ip, still request using node's ip not the elastic ip one.

Comment: hope you NAT is in proper subnet and traffic getting routed from specific instalce

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/de-mystifying-cluster-networking-for-amazon-eks-worker-nodes/